# disable layout in javascript

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

is there an equivalent to

`ZendFrameWork's disableLayout and setNoLayout for javascript`

where i can just print an object to the browser without the website rendering?

The reason i ask is simply convenience and easy of use (for me). it's much easier for me to quickly scan through data this way, than printing out `objects` to `firebug's console`. (finding it hard to click my way through massive sized `objects`).

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout or markup is rendered by Zend and is received by the browser as is. Now technically you can strip the markup out using jQuery if you know where the output starts, but you cannot per se disable the layout using javascript since the browser doesn't know what the layout is and what the content is.

If the content is contained inside a container with id "content" and evrything around it is the layout.

You could do `jQuery("body").html(jQuery("#content"))` and only that part will remain stripping everything else. The css etc will still remain. You can always replace html with a structured rendeition, or simply null the head tag to remove styling. `$("head").remove();`